# Qt: How to share QListWidget Data between QWizard Pages

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

I have a three wizard pages, Page1,Page2 and Page3. In Page one i have a Qlist widget which has some 10 items, and the user selects three of these items and clicks next button. Now before i go to the next page (may be in Page 2 initalizePage() method) I would like to create dynamically one label for each item selected, so in this case three labels. How can i achieve this?
I do not want to use model view, and preferable not even getter functions. The pages are totally different classes and only has a base wizard page common inheritance. Thank you

Comment: If you do not have a model then some kind of getter function would be the way to go and I do not see whats wrong with it. Simply extract the selected items from the list view and provide the required date (probably something as simple as a `QList<QString>`) to the second page.

Comment: @Bowdzone: Inorder to create a getter function again i have to include the page 1 class to the page 2 class and then create an Page1 object to access the getter function.

Comment: Not necessarily, depends on how your Wizard works. I guess some class is responsible for displaying the pages and moving from one to the next, therefore knowing the pages already. I would probably use that to read the selected items and let the next page know them during the transition from page one to page two.

Comment: Thank You @Bowdzone

Comment: @Bowdzone : is it possible to use register filed method to get the value?

Comment: I am not sure what method you mean, please provide a link to the method from the official documentation